# Program type already present: com.android.volley.Cache$Entry

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When I run my Application it returns  this error [image: this error] By searching ,I realised that I have to change dependency in the gradle file but I don't know what to change . This is my build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.9.1'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1'

 implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**FYI**

> `implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'` is <del>[**`DEPRECATED`**](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/README.md#deprecated)</del>

Remove `dependencies` of **`implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'`** from your **`Build.Gradle`**

Than **`Clean-Re-Build-Run`** your project

**EDIT**

[Latest version is](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) **`compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'`**

Comment: also better to take latest version of volley `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'`

Comment: When I added the latest version it returns the same error

Comment: @flora have u removed `implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude volley like below I did and it will work

```
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.volley'
}
```